# Is it possible to call a reducer function from another reducer function (within the same slice) using Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have this small module management slice:

```
const WorkspaceSlice = createSlice({
    name: "workspace",
    initialState: {
        activeModule: null,
        modules:
        {
            ["someModule"]: { ...moduleRenderingData },
        },
    },
    reducers: {
        setActiveModule(state, action)
        {
            state.activeModule = action.payload;
        },
        addModule(state, action)
        {
            const { moduleName, renderingData } = action.payload; 
            if (!state.modules[moduleName])
            {
                state.modules[moduleName] = renderingData;
            }

            // state.activeModule = moduleName; <- basically the same as 'setActiveModule'
            this.setActiveModule(state, action.payload.module); // <- 'this' is undefined
        },
    },
});

export default WorkspaceSlice;
```

What I'm trying to do is call `setActiveModule` from within `addModule` so that I won't have duplicate code, but I get an error because `this` is undefined.
Is there a way to call one reducer from within another? What's the syntax for that?
If not, is it possible to achieve this functionality in another way, assuming I want to keep both `addModule` and `setActiveModule` as separate actions?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `slice` object returned from `createSlice` includes each of the individual case reducer functions you passed in as `slice.caseReducers`, to help with situations like this.

So, you could do:

```js
addModule(state, action) {
    const { moduleName, renderingData } = action.payload; 
    if (!state.modules[moduleName]) {
        state.modules[moduleName] = renderingData;
    }

    WorkspacesSlice.caseReducers.setActiveModule(state, action);
},
```

Also, reducer functions have no `this`, because there are no class instances involved.  They're just functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about caseReducers - I tried with .reducers, but as expected that didn't work either.

Comment: what if have used this passed my reducers to slice.reducers?

Comment: @Jesswin : not sure what you're asking there - can you clarify?

Comment: Calling one reducer from within another, ends in a typescript error `slice implicitly has any type, since it is being referenced in its own initializer`. Although it might work if you want to use the case reducer outside the component, I'm not sure it works from within another reducer.

Comment: @sayandcode try defining the reducer outside of the slice and then adding it to the `reducers` object, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564530/is-it-possible-to-call-a-reducer-function-from-another-reducer-function-within
This fixed typing issues for me.

Comment: @HadasArik That gets rid of type inference for the `state` and `action` right?

Comment: Yes, which is why we show defining those case reducer functions _inside_ the `createSlice` call as the default approach.  You do normally need to declare `action: PayloadAction<MyPayloadType>`, but you get `state` inferred automatically.

Answer (score 5):

The [Redux Toolkit Docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createslice) have an example，You can read how to do it:

```js
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => state + action.payload,
  },
})

// also available:
slice.caseReducers.increment(0, { type: 'increment', payload: 5 })
```